# Evaluate $\iint\limits_D(x^2-2xy+y^2)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$ where $4\leqslant x^2-y^2 \leqslant 16,~-5\leqslant y-\frac{x}{2}\leqslant 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Evaluate
>
> $$I=\iint\limits_D(x^2-2xy+y^2)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$
>
> where $D$ is bounded by $$x^2-y^2=4,~x^2-y^2=16,~y=\frac{x}{2}-5,~y=\frac{x}{2}+1.$$

*Attempt.* The obvious transformation $u=x^2-y^2,~v=2y-x$ has Jacobian determinant

$$det\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}=\frac{1}{det\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}}=\frac{1}{4x-2y},$$
where $x=x(u,v)$ and $y=y(u,v)$. So:
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\iint\limits_{[4,16]\times[-10,2]}\frac{x^2-2xy+y^2}{|4x-2y|}\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v,$$
but the function inside the integral seems compicated enough, in order to turn into a simple function of $u,\,v.$

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with $u = x^2 - y^2, v = 2y-x$ is that it is difficult to express the objective as a function of $u,v$

Which gets me thinking about

$u = x+y\\
v = x-y\\
du dv = 2 dx dy$

This works nice with the objective and one of the functions on the boundary, but not the other.

Our transformed objective is now $\frac 12 v^2$

and the boundaries are $uv = 4, uv = 16, u - 3v = -20, u-3v = 4$

Suppose we try:

$s = uv\\
t = u\\
v = \frac {s}{t} = v\\
u = t$

$du dv = \left|\begin{array}{} \frac{1}{t} &-\frac{s}{t^2}\\1 & 0\end{array}\right|  = \frac {s}{t^2} ds dt$

After this transformation.

objective $\frac {s^3}{2}$

and the boundaries are $s = 4, s = 16, \frac{s}{t} - 3t = -20, \frac {s}{t}-3t = 4$

Can we express isolate $t$ in the following:

$ \frac {s}{t} - 3 t = -20\\
3t^2 - 20 t - s\\
t = \frac {10 \pm \sqrt {100 + 3s}}{3}$

and

$t = \frac {2 \pm \sqrt {4 + 3s}}{3}$

At this point it is worth noting that if we sketch the region as it was originally defined there are, in fact two regions.

[image]

$\int_4^{16}\int_{\frac{2 - \sqrt{4+3s}}{3}}^{\frac{10 - \sqrt{100+3s}}{3}} s^3 \ dt\ ds + \int_4^{16}\int_{\frac{2 + \sqrt{4+3s}}{3}}^{\frac{10 + \sqrt{100+3s}}{3}} s^3 \ dt\ ds$

Rather than the two step transformation we could have said

$u = (x-y)(x+y)\\
v = x+y$

at the start.  But, I didn't know that is what we needed.